# "You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle" No matter what version code set

Tags: android-studio, google-play, version

I am trying to upload a new update for the beta version of my last app on google play store.

I've tried several version codes, 1,2,3,29 !! But no matter what version code is set, it shows this error

> Upload failed
>   You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 29

please note that the last version of the app is actually 1.

Here is a part of my gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 29
        versionName "29.2.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was strange to find the solution, that the problem is not that the app is not being accepted on play store, but some double upload happened because of the bad internet connection, so that the app is keep uploading again, after it is being already uploaded.

I noticed that after finishing the upload it shows again 99% uploading, then the error occured.

When I checked after 2 days, I found that those versions 2,3,29 have been successfully uploaded !

So It is not an issue in the bundle or apk, but on google console in uploading process handling slow internet connections.

Comment: For such case, you can use "Add From Library" option instead of "Upload". By clicking "Add From Library" you will get list of all uploaded build, you can find the latest uploaded version.

Answer (score 24):

[Google play sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuT9c.png)

try to explore **Artifact library** at the sidebar , you can delete your previous uploaded app and then reupload your new app .

Comment: I didn't see anything in the Artifact library to delete the previous versions.

Comment: @ijt you might have published your apk to live

Comment: @NMI Is it now called "App bundle explorer"?

Comment: it's called app bundle explorer now and I think this one should be the better answer

Answer (score 4):

When you see this error, scroll down and click save,
Open Artifact Library from left side panel,
Find your uploaded APK and remove,
Reupload the same APK

Answer (score 3):

go to App Bunder Explorer at the sidebar and delete your previous uploaded app and then re-upload your new app.

Answer (score 2):

For flutter users, you have to change the version in `pubsec.yaml` and not in the android folders.

```
version:A.B.C+X
eg: 1.0.0+2
```

`x` is the `version code` and `a, b, c` are `version name`.

Do not forget to execute `flutter build ipa` or `flutter run` after this step.

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing using Flutter:

```
version:A.B.C+X
eg: 1.0.0+2
```

Modifying X is a must because X is the version code.
Then run:

```
flutter pub get
flutter clean
flutter build appbundle
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For flutter users, u can also try directly replacing the version code in android projects `build.gradle` of app like this :

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '7'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.2.1'
}
```

with this:

```
def flutterVersionCode = '7'

def flutterVersionName = '1.2.1'
```

Be sure to update it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just after a successful build, with the success message you get two options: `Locate` and `Analyze`. Click `Analyze`, it shows you the version, and there check if the issue is with android studio.